Quotient of two subgroups of the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^r$ and Smith Normal Form.
Suppose we have free abelian groups $H \leq G \leq \mathbb{Z}^r$. I'd like to understand the quotient $G/H$. Suppose $\operatorname{rank}(H)=p$, $\operatorname{rank}(G)=s$ and that $(h_i)_{i=1,..,p}, (g_i)_{i=1,..,s}$ are coefficients of the Smith Normal Form associated to H and G respectively. I'd like to understand the quotient $G/H$ and I have two ideas:

It must be that each $g_i$ divides $h_i$ upon reordering the coefficients of H.
The quotient $G/H$ is $\bigoplus_{i=1}^p \mathbb{Z} /(h_i/g_i) \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}^{s-p}$.

These are only suppositions, which I couldn't either disprove or prove. Could you please enlighten me on that?
If they are wrong, what is the relation between the Smith Normal Forms and the quotient $G/H$?
Thank you.
Edit: for the second point I found a counterexample with $H = \operatorname{span}\begin{pmatrix}8 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}, G = \operatorname{span}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. The first point is still verified though.
